# couchdb change notifications

Tags: couchdb

What does the changes API actually do? does it list the last revision of each document + deleted documents?

or to put it this way:

Can the change notifications feature of couchdb be used to list all the documents that match a query?

For example, if I have the filter function:

```
search = function(doc,req)
{
  return (doc.min && doc.max && doc.min < req.query.q && doc.max > req.query.q)
}
```

will I get all the documents that match doc.min < somevalue < doc.max here?

> http :// server / database / _changes ? filter=doctype/search & q=somevalue

For my test database it appears to be so, but what if I have a large database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every write to the database is given what is known as a `seqnum`. (or sequence number) A log of those writes is stored with the document `_id`, `_rev`, amongst other information about the write. (See [this section](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html) of the CouchDB book online.) A newly-created document gets the next `seqnum` (old seqnum + 1). A document update, on the other hand, also appends a new `seqnum` but also removes the document's old one from from the log. If you list all documents ordered by `seqnum`, you get a timeline of the evolution of the data.

Calling the `_changes` API retrieves that list. And since every revision is saved in it's entirity (not just a delta of changes) then you can reconstruct everything that has changed in that database since a particular `seqnum`.

Running a compaction removes old document revisions, but does not affect the seqnum or _changes data. This is because _changes shows only the latest (live) revisions of the documents.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I took the liberty of clarifying the compaction point, and then I got slightly carried away with an update to your initial intro. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: so all the documents in the database (with their latest revision number) will be in the list (and those that were deleted)?

Comment: Correct, and until you run a compaction, you can still retrieve a deleted document with a valid `_rev` number.

Comment: Thanks! My only need is to run the filter function i defined on *all* existing documents. I think I got the things straight :)

Comment: Dominic, could you please help, how to retrieve just deleted docment? I get {"_id":"25efa4ec8489d8b89b34c5cad6000059","_rev":"3-a982bd6dccce8f405433f8453ab86880","_deleted":true}, but I'd like to get it's contents, but rev=2 is not available in _changes log.

Comment: Well, I've figured this out, see [CouchDB - retrieve just deleted document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854883/couchdb-retrieve-just-deleted-document/10857330#10857330) if interested.