# How can I query pouchdb for deleted documents?

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I would like to list currently deleted documents in order to provide the ability to undelete one or more.

How can I query couchdb for deleted documents? I am actually using pouchdb.

Although [this POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857330/913295) nicely describes how to query for and undelete a document, it requires an id of an existing doc.

I am looking for a way to query for all documents that have been deleted. The POST cites making a query for all changes. That query returns all documents that have been deleted IN ADDITION to any that have been edited/changed.

I am looking only for documents that have been deleted. Think querying for documents in the 'trash bin'. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve just deleted document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854883/retrieve-just-deleted-document)

Comment: At this point I am thinking to add a deleted_at datetime value to each document. Using this I can emulate Laravel soft delete functionality. All my general queries would exclude docs with deleted_at value. That is unless there is a more elegant way to achieve this natively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting from couch 2.1.0, you can add various selectors to `_changes` feed. So your request to output only deleted documents will be:

curl -X POST -H "content-Type: application/json"  "http://adm:pass@127.0.0.1:15984/tracks/_changes?filter=_selector" -d '{"selector": {"_deleted": true}}'

Answer (score 4):

You can add a filter to the _changes feed in PouchDB: https://pouchdb.com/api.html#filtered-changes

```
var changes = db.changes({
  filter: function(doc) {
    return doc._deleted;
  }
}).on('change', function(change) {
  console.log(change.id);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

For an all-in-one solution combining the `open_revs` tip from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16827094), here's the TypeScript code I came up with:

```js
const db = new PouchDB('my-db');

async function deletedDocIds(): Promise<string[]> {
  const ret: string[] = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.changes({filter: d => d._deleted})
        .on('change', c => ret.push(c.id))
        .on('complete', () => resolve(ret))
        .on('error', e => reject(e));
  });
}

async function deletedDocs() {
  const ids = await deletedDocIds();
  return Promise.all(ids.map(id => db.get(id, {revs: true, open_revs: 'all'}).then(x => {
    const revs = (x[0].ok as any)._revisions;
    const lastRev = (revs.start - 1) + '-' + revs.ids[1];
    return db.get(id, {rev: lastRev}); // with Pouchdb keys too
  })));
}
```

Calling `deletedDocs()` will return a promise of an array of *all* deleted docs as per the rev *just prior* to deletion.

N.B., the elements of the array will include PouchDb metadata as well as your document's keys.

N.B. 2, version 6.1.3 of DefinitelyTyped's TypeScript bindings for [pouchdb-browser](http://npmjs.com/@types/pouchdb-browser) which I'm using here (should work for `@types/pouchdb` too though) doesn't seem to know about the `_revisions` key, hence the `as any` escape hatch.

N.B. 3, this should be trivial to manually translate to plain JS, just delete the type declarations and coercions (`:`, `as`, and whatever token follows these).