# how to recover couchDB documents

Tags: couchdb

I see this has been discussed previously (here:[Retrieve just deleted document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854883/retrieve-just-deleted-document)) but I am having some trouble understanding.

Given I have a database named "test" running on IP address 127.0.0.1:5984, and a document with the ID "xyz123":

Get all the revisions of the deleted document with the following request:

```
$db/$id?revs=true&open_revs=all
```

Where `$db` is your CouchDB database name and `$id` is your deleted document id.

Does this mean:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/"xyz123"?revs=true&open_revs=all ??
```

I am not sure of the correct syntax for submitting "`$id`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` becomes part of the URL, no quoting necessary.  Your example call would be `GET http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/xyz123?revs=true&open_revs=all`.

For reference, the [documents API area](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/document/common.html) has some basic id examples.