# Retrieve deleted document with Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-2.0

I have deleted documents by mistake in Cloudant but can't find a way to retrieve them. I have followed this tuto: http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2013/11/couchdb-restoring-deletedupdated.html

And this answer: [Retrieve just deleted document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854883/retrieve-just-deleted-document)

Without success... What is the normal procedure? Each time I try to get a specific revision of deleted document: `https://address/mydb/$id?rev=$rev` I get only a partial document

Answer (score 1):

If you're quick, you can retrieve the body of a recently deleted document with `GET /mydb/id?rev=x` where `x` is the old revision number. But periodically Cloudant (and CouchDB) performs a "compaction" operation that removes the bodies of older revisions that are no longer required. That would leave older document with only its `_id`, `_rev` and `_deleted=true`, which is, I suspect, what you are seeing.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but I'll point out it's really a side effect of using the `DELETE` method, which is what "clears out" the final revision that remains. If you save a doc with `"_deleted": true` instead, you can actually leave other fields in that "final revision" and they won't get compacted away. (I explain more at http://n.exts.ch/2012/11/baleting if you're interested.)