# Recover recently deleted couchdb documents

Tags: couchdb, fauxton

I logged in to my couchDb fauxton UI, selected a database, and clicked select all and deleted the documents. Is there a way to recover them from the UI or is there any command I can run that will restore all of them?

Comment: Deleted documents are never truly deleted. There are still tombstone documents around with `"_deleted": true` keys. And if you haven't compacted the database, you can recover the old revisions, too. But you'll have to write a script to do this. There's no single command to just restore deleted documents.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854883/retrieve-just-deleted-document), in the answers you'll find solutions how to restore `_deleted` CouchDB documents.

Another explanation can be found in [this blog post regarding "CouchDB restoring deleted/updated documents and their data"](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.com/2013/11/couchdb-restoring-deletedupdated.html).